# Why is np.where transforming some of my data into NaN values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, nan

I wanted to split data values if \n was present in a column. This is a snippet of my original data column (note I casted this column to a `object` datatype):

```
0               881567905
1               881046000
2               881046025
3               882935053
4               881006805
5               882130610
6               882036810
7               882428300
8               882428400
9    884343355\n183055900
```

I split the data on `'\n'` and then returned back a list anywhere the data had multiple list elements created using the `np.where()` function. While it did accomplish that to a degree, it also created random `Nan` values.

```
0                 881567905
1                 881046000
2                 881046025
3                       NaN
4                       NaN
5                       NaN
6                       NaN
7                 882428300
8                 882428400
9    [884343355, 183055900]
```

As you can see, there is not really any length, datatype, or structural difference in the values that did not transform and the ones that were replaced with NaN. The code I used to split and replace was:

```
file_no = df['file_no'].str.split("\n")
df['file_no'] = np.where(file_no.str.len()==1,file_no.str[0],file_no)
```

I used it on other columns that were very similarly structured and it did not create these `NaN` values. I also reloaded my environment in case I had messed a smaller step up but the only code prior to this was this:

```
df = r'Z:\clients.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(path,sheet_name="Master List",header=0,engine="openpyxl")
df = df.rename(columns={'Our File #':'file_no', 'ID #':'ID'})
df = df.astype({'file_no':'object'})
df = df[df.file_no.notnull()]
```

Does anyone have any ideas why these `NaN` values may be replacing those pandas values?

Comment: i suspect some of those 882935053 values are kept as numbers against which pandas' .str.split gives back NaN as it cannot split a non-string. so np.where isn't to blame i believe, and perhaps try `df = df.astype({"file_no": "str"})` instead of object

Comment: It still was giving me NaN values but I ended up finding a solution. `df['file_no'] = df['file_no'].apply(lambda x: x.split('\n') if isinstance(x, str) and '\n' in x else x)`. Created the desired output!

Comment: it works for me, when typing in your example with proper strings

Comment: when trying to understand a `where` look at  3 arguments by them selves.  It also help to look at the result of the wherree before assignment back tio frame. Also attention dtype and type.  Pandas does not show quotes on strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're being caught by the fact that `regex` is `True` by default when the splitter is more than a single character on `pd.Series.str.split`.

```py
# Force conversion to strings
df.file_no = df.file_no.astype(str)

# Split on `\\n` with regex=False - you may actually just need `\n`
df.file_no = df.file_no.str.split("\\n", regex=False)

# Your np.where was fine, but can be simplified with `pd.Series.mask`
df.file_no = df.file_no.mask(df.file_no.str.len().eq(1), df.file_no.str[0])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                  file_no
0               881567905
1               881046000
2               881046025
3               882935053
4               881006805
5               882130610
6               882036810
7               882428300
8               882428400
9  [884343355, 183055900]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found using the .apply method worked perfectly! I would be open to learning another solution if there is a better approach but this worked great!
`df['file_no'] = df['file_no'].apply(lambda x: x.split('\n') if isinstance(x, str) and '\n' in x else x)`
Output:

```
0                  881567905
1                  881046000
2                  881046025
3                  882935053
4                  881006805
5                  882130610
6                  882036810
7                  882428300
8                  882428400
9     [884343355, 183055900]
10                 884080135
11                 881076100
12                 885052617
13                 885148004
14                 874545945
```